# Spring Data Specifications, how to query LIKE for a @OneToMany relationship?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity, called "Client", which contains a List users.

```
public class Client {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="client")
    private List<User> users;
}
```

I want to write a query which does something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Client client
JOIN Users user
ON user.client_id = client.client_id
WHERE ( user.name LIKE '%name%' AND user.role = 'ADMINISTRATOR' )
```

Does anyone know how to do with using Specifications?

Normally, if there was one user, I would do something like this below. But since we have here a List I am not sure how to approach this situation.

```
Path<User> user = root.<User> get("user");
queryPredicates.add(cb.like(cb.upper(user .<String>get("name")), getLikePattern(queryString)));
queryPredicates.add(cb.like(cb.upper(user .<String>get("role")), "ADMINISTRATOR));
```

If I wanted to compare an equal, I could construct a User object and do something like this:

```
User user = new User();
// set properties
queryPredicates.add(cb.isMember(user, root.<Collection<User>>get("users")));
```

I could do something like:

```
Path<List<User>> users = root.<List<User>>get("users");
```

But then what?

Thanks,
Joachim

Comment: cannot do it on user side?

Comment: Ah, yes, it can be done. But I'd have to merge two result lists instead of using one Specification. Let me try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution could be on user side, i.e. in UserRepository:

```
findByClientAndRoleAndNameLike(Client client, String role, String name)
```

Comment: So yes, this works indeed. The only downside is that I first have to retrieve already a List<Client> clients (with some other specifications), and then make a query via the UserRepository to find all the Users which match the criteria and add their specific client to the already established list. It works well, and probably it's easier and more readable than doing more advanced stuff with Specifications would be...

Answer (score 0):

You can use JPA entity manager query to do something like that :

```
List<Client> clients = (List<Client>) entityManager
    .createQuery(
        "select c from Client c join c.users u where u.role='ADMISTRATOR' and u.name like :name")
    .setParameter("name", "foo").getResultList();
```

You can find more about this [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbtl.html#bnbtq)